# Wash sale rule on sale of a stock for a loss

Tags: stocks, wash-sale

Does the wash sale rule also apply when you sell a position for a loss and one week later you buy it again but this time at a higher price?

Comment: What country are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

The USA, UK and other countries have a wash sale rule.  It is triggered by the acquisition of substantially identical replacement shares (stock or option) within 30 days before or after realizing a loss.

If you are not in the USA or UK, check with your broker and/or regulatory agencies.